# ImageButton OnClick event not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an Imageutton in asp.net. I want when I clicked on it, an event fire (that code of this event is written in c#).

asp code is:

```
<div align="right">
    <table dir="rtl">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgScoreStar1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/ScoreStars/Star0_28px.png" OnClick="Star_Onclick" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and behind code is:

```
protected void Star_Onclick(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    //do something
}
```

but ever fire click event (I tested it by breakpoint).

Another question: When I click on ImageButton, postback happens. how can I avoid this?

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check:
1. Check CausesValidation property. Test with making it false.
2. Use Page.RegisterRequiresRaiseEvent(ImageButton)

Comment: Hi @Sunil. 1. Setting CausesValidation property to false, not works. 2. Where should I use Page.RegisterRequiresRaiseEvent(ImageButton)?

Answer (score 0):

How to avoid postback.

1. Add ScriptManager. There must be only one ScriptManager in one page.
   (If you are using Master page, add to master page and no need to add anymore in nested content page)
2. Add UpdatePanel and add your desired content including imagebutton to ContentTemplate of UpdatePanel.

Comment: I never used ScriptManager in my project. Now, when I use it, an error occurs that: `InvalidOperationException: Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page`. And when I clear ScriptManager, an error occurs  that: `InvalidOperationException: The control with ID '' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it`

Answer (score 0):

> in aspx

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate> 
  <div align="right">
        <table dir="rtl">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgScoreStar1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/ScoreStars/Star0_28px.png" OnClick="Star_Onclick" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
 </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

> in cs

```
protected void Star_Onclick(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    //do something
}
```

> i checked its working you need to check property of that button try to add another button and change **ID** of button that will Ignore the property that are stopping click event

Comment: I never used ScriptManager in my project. Now, when I use it, an error occurs that: `InvalidOperationException: Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page`. And when I clear ScriptManager, an error occurs  that: `InvalidOperationException: The control with ID '' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it`

Comment: can you show your all aspx code its look like you are using two script manager

Comment: if you will show all aspx code then it will be easy to find the main problem

Answer (score 0):

You can surround your Page load sequence like this...

```
if(!IsPostBack){

//PageLoad code

}
```

Then write code under the button click event.
The button click event should work

It worked for me!